# Passing multiple arguments as a list in R

Tags: r, text-mining, quanteda

I wish to pass a list of arguments as a vector to another command in R. I do not want to repeat the same set of arguments every time.

This is the code that I have to run 6 times for each `$full_text` column of data frames ranging `t1 to t6`.

```
    library(quanteda)

t1t <- tokens(t1$full_text, what = 'word', remove_numbers = TRUE,
                 remove_punct = TRUE,
                 remove_symbols = TRUE,
                 remove_separators = TRUE,
                 remove_twitter = TRUE,
                 remove_hyphens = TRUE,
                 remove_url = TRUE)
t1t <- tokens_tolower(t1t)
t1t <- tokens_select(t1t, stopwords(), selection = "remove")
t1t <- unlist(t1t)
t1t <- unique(t1t)
t1t <- as.data.frame(t1t)
t1t <- as.data.frame.matrix(t1t)
```

Is there a way to pass a one-time argument.

Comment: Can you try `params <- list("remove_numbers" = TRUE, ..., "what" = "word")` (notice it's a list and only the names are quoted), and then `t1 <- do.call(tokens, params)`. See the documentation of do.call [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/do.call.html).

Comment: no it didn't work. gives `Error in tokens.default(what = function (string, start = 1L, end = start,  : 
  tokens() only works on character, corpus, tokens objects.`

Comment: @ambrishdhaka I have edited the answer based on your update. Please check if it is of any help.

Comment: It's not really possible to answer this without knowing what format of answer you want. Separate data.frames? a list of data.frames? one data.frame with a second column identifying the original document? BTW if you only want the unique tokens you can use `types(tokens(txt))` (where `txt` is a character or corpus input).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the error message `tokens` expect character vector, corpus or tokens as input. You are passing a dataframe to it. Pass the respective column of text to it instead.

Also `tokens` can process vectors so you can pass multiple columns together as one vector.

```
library(quanteda)

tokens(c(t1$colname, t2$colname, t3$colname), what = "word", remove_numbers = TRUE, 
  remove_punct = TRUE, remove_symbols = TRUE, remove_separators = TRUE, 
  remove_twitter = TRUE, remove_hyphens  =TRUE, remove_url = TRUE)
```

Based on the update and taking an example from the help page of `?tokens`

```
t1 <- data.frame(full_text = "#textanalysis is MY <3 4U @myhandle gr8 #stuff :-)", 
              stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
t2 <- data.frame(full_text = c("This is $10 in 999 different ways,\n up and down; 
    left and right!", "@kenbenoit working: on #quanteda 2day\t4ever, 
    http://textasdata.com?page=123."), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

We can create a function to apply it to all dataframes

```
 complete_function <- function(x) {
   t1t <- tokens(x, what = 'word', remove_numbers = TRUE,
                  remove_punct = TRUE,
                  remove_symbols = TRUE,
                  remove_separators = TRUE,
                  remove_twitter = TRUE,
                  remove_hyphens = TRUE,
                  remove_url = TRUE)
   t1t <- tokens_tolower(t1t)
   t1t <- tokens_select(t1t, stopwords(), selection = "remove")
   t1t <- unlist(t1t)
   t1t <- unique(t1t)
   t1t <- as.data.frame(t1t)
   t1t <- as.data.frame.matrix(t1t)
}
```

Then use `mget` to get dataframes `t1`, `t2`, `t3` etc and apply the function to `"full_text"` column of each dataframe.

```
lapply(mget(ls(pattern = "^t\\d+")), function(x) complete_function(x$full_text))

#$t1
#           t1t
#1 textanalysis
#2           4u
#3     myhandle
#4          gr8
#5        stuff

#$t2
#        t1t
#1 different
#2      ways
#3      left
#4     right
#5 kenbenoit
#6   working
#7  quanteda
#8      2day
#9     4ever
```

Comment: that's what I have been doing, the mute point is not to repeat the set of arguments for each dataframe. The column name thing is a good point, I shall see if it is the issue.

Comment: @ambrishdhaka You can call `tokens` only once combining the columns from all the dataframe. I added an example as well.

Comment: @ambrishdhaka Sorry, not clear. Can you provide an example with expected output ?

Comment: `c("analysis", "us", "military", "downplays", "district", "control", 
"taliban", "gains", "ground", "afghanistan", "billroggio", "writes", 
"fdd's", "longwarjournal", "adammantine", "benjaminnorton", "stronger", 
"ever", "infact", "negotiating")` This is the desired result.

Comment: I have gone through your suggestion but the results are different when a vector is passed and when each column is given individual treatment. Very different results occur.

Comment: Using the code above you get output of class `tokens`. If you want to combine all of them into one character vector you can wrap it in `as.character()` like `as.character(t1)` or if you want to keep them separate use `lapply`, `lapply(t1, as.character)`. where `t1` is output of `tokens(c(df1$txt3, df2$txt4), what = "word"....`